Problems with Telegram Bot in Python
I wrote this code:
    import sqlite3
    from typing import Final
    from telegram import Update
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, ContextTypes,                      CallbackContext, ChatMemberHandler

    TOKEN: Final = ''
    BOT_USERNAME: Final = '@NeoTecnoAlCentroBot'

    #Id dell'user principale (IO - SmokeDeath10)
    ID_USER_PRINCIPALE = '5836602747'

    #Crea connessione a database
    conn = sqlite3.connect('comandi.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    #Crea le tabelle se non esistono già
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comandi (nome text, messaggio text)''')
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comandi (user_id integer, username text)''')
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS utenti (user_id integer, username text)''')

    #Aggiungi l'utente principale agli utenti
    c.execute("INSERT INTO utenti VALUES (?,?)", (ID_USER_PRINCIPALE, None))
    conn.commit()

    def crea_comando(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
        """Permette agli utenti autorizzati di creare un comando personalizzato."""
        user_id = update.message.from_user.id
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE user_id=?", (user_id,))
        if c.fetchone() is not None:
        args = context.args
            if len(args) >= 2:
                nome_comando = args[0]
                messaggio = ' '.join(args[1:])
                c.execute("INSERT INTO comandi VALUES (?,?)", (nome_comando, messaggio))
                conn.commit()
                update.message.reply_text(f'Comando {nome_comando} creato con successo.')
            else:
                update.message.reply_text('Uso: /crea_comando <nome_comando> <messaggio>')
        else:
            update.message.reply_text('Non hai i permessi per creare comandi.')

    def autorizza_utente(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
        """Permette all'utente principale di autorizzare un altro utente."""
        username = update.message.from_user.username
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE username=?", (username,))
        if c.fetchone() is not None:
            args = context.args
            if len(args) == 1:
                username = args[0][1:]  # Rimuove il carattere '@'
                c.execute("SELECT user_id FROM utenti WHERE username=?", (username,))
                user_id = c.fetchone()
                if user_id is not None:
                    c.execute("INSERT INTO utenti VALUES (?,?)", (user_id[0], username))
                    conn.commit()
                    update.message.reply_text(f'Utente @{username} autorizzato con successo.')
                else:
                    update.message.reply_text('Username non trovato.')
            else:
                update.message.reply_text('Uso: /autorizza_utente @username')
        else:
            update.message.reply_text('Non hai i permessi per autorizzare utenti.')

    def aggiorna_utente(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
        """Aggiorna l'username e l'ID dell'utente quando entra nel gruppo o cambia il suo username."""
        user_id = update.chat_member.new_chat_member.user.id
        username = update.chat_member.new_chat_member.user.username
        c.execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO utenti VALUES (?,?)", (user_id, username))
        conn.commit()

    def rimuovi_utente(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
        """Rimuove l'username e l'ID dell'utente quando viene rimosso dal gruppo."""
        user_id = update.chat_member.old_chat_member.user.id
        c.execute("DELETE FROM utenti WHERE user_id=?", (user_id,))
        conn.commit()

    def tagga_utenti(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
        """Tagga gli utenti in un singolo messaggio o in più messaggi."""
        c.execute("SELECT username FROM utenti")
        utenti = [row[0] for row in c.fetchall()]
        for i in range(0, len(utenti), 10):
            tags = ' '.join(f'@{utente}' for utente in utenti[i:i+10])
            update.message.reply_text(tags)

    def invia_privato(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
        """Invia un messaggio privato a tutti i membri del gruppo."""
        if update.message.from_user.username == ID_USER_PRINCIPALE:
            args = context.args
            if args:
                messaggio = ' '.join(args)
                c.execute("SELECT user_id FROM utenti")
                utenti = [row[0] for row in c.fetchall()]
                for utente in utenti:
                    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=utente, text=messaggio)
            else:
                update.message.reply_text('Uso: /invia_privato <messaggio>')
        else:
            update.message.reply_text('Non hai i permessi per inviare messaggi privati.')

    def echo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
        """Risponde con messaggi preimpostati o comandi personalizzati."""
        comando = update.message.text[1:]
        c.execute("SELECT messaggio FROM comandi WHERE nome=?", (comando,))
        messaggio = c.fetchone()
        if messaggio is not None:
            update.message.reply_text(messaggio[0])

    def main() -> None:
        """Avvia il bot."""
        updater = Updater('7498845724:AAEI2GTjXMZgGo3S99iBw_OgoKh7Zshf-Oc', use_context=True)

        # Ottieni il dispatcher per registrare i gestori
        dp = updater.dispatcher

        # su differenti comandi - rispondi in Telegram
        dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
        dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("crea_comando", crea_comando, pass_args=True))
        dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("autorizza_utente", autorizza_utente, pass_args=True))
        dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("tagga_utenti", tagga_utenti))
        dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("invia_privato", invia_privato, pass_args=True))
        dp.add_handler(ChatMemberHandler(aggiorna_utente, ChatMemberHandler.CHAT_MEMBER_UPDATED))
        dp.add_handler(ChatMemberHandler(rimuovi_utente, ChatMemberHandler.CHAT_MEMBER_UPDATED))

        # su messaggi non comando - rispondi con lo stesso messaggio in Telegram
        dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.command, echo))

        # Avvia il Bot
        updater.start_polling()

        # Esegui il bot fino a quando non si preme Ctrl-C o il processo non riceve SIGINT,
        # SIGTERM o SIGABRT. Questo dovrebbe essere usato maggiormente per l'esecuzione del bot
        # in background.
        updater.idle()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()


But when I start main the terminal print this issues:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\NeoTecnoAlCentroBotPrincipale\.venv\Scripts\Bot.py", line 135, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\NeoTecnoAlCentroBotPrincipale\.venv\Scripts\Bot.py", line 109, in main
    updater = Updater('7498845724:AAEI2GTjXMZgGo3S99iBw_OgoKh7Zshf-Oc', use_context=True)
TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_context'

I looked at the version of python-telegram-bot to see if it was compatible if it is above 12.0

The Exception says the keyword use_context is unexpected.... in the line where you create an Updater, you pass the argument use_context=True. But the documentation does not list that as a parameter of the Updater constructor

You left your Private Bot Token in your code. You should revoke it ASAP by talking to the @BotFather. People might abuse the token.

Check the python-telegram-bot version you are on. The latest version is 21.3. You seem to have the code for versions below 13.0. Consider downgrading the module. However, you also have to downgrade urllib3 and requests modules.
